# Why the characters never rotating?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want them to rotate smooth slowly by 180 degrees each one from another side.
The first to rotate from left to right and the second from right to left.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnimatorController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator[] animators;
    public Transform target;
    public float speed = 1f;
    public float rotationSpeed;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < animators.Length; i++)
        {
            animators[i].SetFloat("Walking Speed", speed);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float distanceFromTarget = Vector3.Distance(animators[2].transform.position, target.position);
        if (distanceFromTarget < 15)
        {
            float speed = (distanceFromTarget / 15) / 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < animators.Length; i++)
            {
                animators[i].SetFloat("Walking Speed", speed);
            }
        }

        if (distanceFromTarget < 2f)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < animators.Length; i++)
            {
                animators[i].SetFloat("Walking Speed", 0);
            }

            animators[0].transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(animators[0].transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0), Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
            animators[1].transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(animators[1].transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0), Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
        }
    }
}
```

It's getting to this two lines but does nothing:

```
animators[0].transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(animators[0].transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0), Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
animators[1].transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(animators[1].transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0), Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
```

I also tried instead Quaternion.RotateTowards on both then Quaternion.Slerp but it also didn't rotate them.

Comment: What are their `rotation` values at the start? What value do you have for `rotationSpeed`?

Comment: @Ruzihm both on start values are 0,180,0 and the rotationSpeed is set to 10

Comment: Ok found the problem for the rotation. Both lines should be Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0) instead Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0) and the speed is 50. But how do I make that one of them will rotate from the other side ? I tried -0 but it's not working they are both rotating from the same direction.

Comment: Tried it with 360 or 359? Would this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make them move in different directions, set them slightly away from 180 degrees, so the closest direction is opposite for them:

```
if (distanceFromTarget < 2f)
{

    // If they haven't yet rotated, start them rotating in different directions
    if (animators[0].transform.eulerAngles.y == 180f) { 
        float epsilon = 0.001f;
        animators[0].transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 180f - epsilon, 0f);
        animators[1].transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 180f + epsilon, 0f);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < animators.Length; i++)
    {
        animators[i].SetFloat("Walking Speed", 0);
    }

    animators[0].transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(animators[0].transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0), Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
    animators[1].transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(animators[1].transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0), Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
}
```